# OutputText value calling a @readOnly method

Tags: visualforce, soql, account, remote-action, read-only

I want to display the total number of `Accounts` in an `<apex:outputText>`.

For that, I did :

**VF :**

```
<apex:outputText value="{!$totalAccounts}"/>
```

**Controller :**

```
public Integer getTotalAccounts() {
        return [Select count() FROM Account];
}
```

But I encounter the limit when I have more than 50000 Accounts.

So, I try to use the `@readOnly` keyword on my method but get this error on my IDE :

> Only WebsService, RemoteAction, or Schedulable.execute() methods can
>   be marked as read-only

The only way is to use the `@RemoteAction` but I don't know how to do that.

How can I call a `@RemoteAction` method to get my total `Accounts` number and then display it in my `outputText` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use Javascript (with the [AJAX Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/)) to call a  `@RemoteAction`  method (must be static).

In your case, you can define a `div` in your visualforce page (instead of outputText -> no need to a getter in the controller) with a Javascript `<script>` like this (replace YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME with the appropriate controller name):

```
<div id="totalAccounts"></div> 
                <script>
                Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    '{!$RemoteAction.YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME.getRemoteTotalAccounts}',
                        function(result){
                            document.getElementById('totalAccounts').innerHTML = result;
                        }

                    );
                </script>
```

and in YOUR_CONTROLLER define this statis method:

```
@RemoteAction
@readOnly
public static Integer getRemoteTotalAccounts() {
     return [Select count() FROM Account];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only displaying information at the VF page, you could switch it over to [read only mode](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_controller_readonly_context_pagelevel.htm):

```
<apex:page controller="PageController" readOnly="true">
    <apex:outputText value="{!$totalAccounts}"/>
</apex:page>
```

This would relax the limits up to 1 million records.

Comment: No I do some DML operations in this page.