# @RemoteAction in Lightning web components

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, remote-access

How i can migrate this code to Lightning web component:

```
<div id="totalAccounts"></div> 
            <script>
            Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME.getRemoteTotalAccounts}',
                    function(result){
                        document.getElementById('totalAccounts').innerHTML = result;
                    }

                );
            </script>
```

Apex Method:

```
@RemoteAction
@readOnly
public static Integer getRemoteTotalAccounts() {
     return [Select count() FROM Account];
}
```

Base publication: [OutputText value calling a @readOnly method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50269/outputtext-value-calling-a-readonly-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the wire method examples with apex methods [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex)

Basically, would make the apex method aura enabled by adding:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
```

You would 'wire' that method to the component via import e.g.

```
import getRemoteTotalAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME.getRemoteTotalAccounts';
```

And then in the LWC, the wire method will bind the result to a property/function that you can expose on the page

```
 @wire(getRemoteTotalAccounts ) contactcount;
```

Comment: If I need more than 50 thousand records the @wire will bring them without problem?

Comment: That I don't know -  as far as I know, the limits with aura cacheable are the same as they were with VF, but not sure if the VF ReadOnly mode is the same with cacheable

Comment: @AlexM. It's irrelevant in recent releases; the way COUNT works [has been changed](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_soql_count_limits.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can use apex method directly, no need to use remote action.

Write @auraEnabled method in Apex.

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Integer getRemoteTotalAccounts() {
    return [Select count() FROM Account];
}
```

Import method in Lwc.

```
import getRemoteTotalAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/Classname.getRemoteTotalAccounts';
```

Wire method in js.

```
@wire(getRemoteTotalAccounts) result;
```

Use `result` in HTML like `{result.data}`;